# dnspython PTR query podman DNS

Tags: python, python-3.6, podman, dnspython

i wonder if anyone with a keen eye can help me. It appears podman adds multiple PTR records which prevents stops me from using socket.gethostbyaddr as it only returns the last answer in alpine. I decided to try dnspython, however, i cannot seem to get it to return any PTR's:

Note: podman DNS is 10.89.0.1. i statically configured for testing but by default it would pick this up from resolv.conf

```
#dnspython 2.2.1 
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver._nameservers=['10.89.0.1']
print(resolver._nameservers)
lookup = 'database'
ips = resolver.query(lookup, 'A')
for ip in ips:
  ip = str(ip)
  print(f"database IP:{ip}")
  try:
    answer = resolver.resolve_address(ip)
    print(answer)
  except Exception as e:
    print("error:",e)
```

when i run this code i get:

['10.89.0.1']
database IP:10.89.0.223
error: The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: **223.0.89.10.in-addr.arpa**. IN PTR

If i complete a capture, i see the response come back as expected :

```
Domain Name System (response)
    Transaction ID: 0xc291
    Flags: 0x8100 Standard query response, No error
    Questions: 1
    Answer RRs: 3
    Authority RRs: 0
    Additional RRs: 0
    Queries
        223.0.89.10.in-addr.arpa: type PTR, class IN
            Name: 223.0.89.10.in-addr.arpa
            [Name Length: 24]
            [Label Count: 6]
            Type: PTR (domain name PoinTeR) (12)
            Class: IN (0x0001)
    Answers
        <Root>: type PTR, class IN, database_1
        <Root>: type PTR, class IN, database
        <Root>: type PTR, class IN, 6a5f9e86a946
    [Request In: 1057]
    [Time: 0.000069000 seconds]
```

Can anyone help me understand why the python code is not performing as expected?

I get the correct response when using DIG

```
dig +short  @10.89.0.1 PTR  223.0.89.10.in-addr.arpa.
database_1.
database.
6a5f9e86a946.


dig +short  @10.89.0.1 -x 10.89.0.223
database_1.
database.
6a5f9e86a946.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

tried the same query using dig